# GAE Python - Accessing values in Response object

Tags: python, api, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm getting response from an API where response.text looks as follows:

```
{
  "message": "Queued. Thank you.",
  "id": "<emailID@somedomain.com>"
}
```

I want to access the ID, for which I am using following code:

```
response.text['id']
```

However this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However if I take the copy of the response and create a normal dictionary with it, this works exactly as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `response.text` is a string, and well, string indices must be integers.

You know it's a JSON string however, so just convert it:

```
import json
data = json.loads(response.text)
print data['id']
```